# Perl doesn’t connect to Oracle DB in cronjob

Tags: perl, cron

I’ve created a Perl script that connects to Oracle database and works perfectly when I launch it manually, but doesn’t work as cronjob.

It seems like, the script is unable to connect to the database.

I put a print statement before and after the statement that connects to the DB, and then I can see only the first message.
Perl script:

```
print 'Before connection';
my $dbh = DBI->connect(«dbi:Oracle:MYDB1», $user, $pwd, {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0});
print 'After connection';
```

Cron :

```
*/1 * * * * /u01/script.pl >> /u01/msg.log
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: The cron environment is usually very restricted see what if any differences there are in %ENV when your script works and does not.

Comment: Hi Chris. There is no error, only the first message I put before dB connection statement.

Comment: I created a sh script with export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/my/oracle/client and LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/my/oracle/client/lib:. I called the perl script in the sh script, finally I called the sh script in crontab, but the results remains the same.

Comment: Your quotes `‘` `«` look a bit funky. You should only use the regular quotes, not the fancy ones. Or use `q()` or `qq()` for single/double quotes respectively.

Comment: At the end of your line in the cron tab, you need to add ` 2>&1` so that your errors show up in the log. That will help you debug, but most likely it’s due to something in your environment/shell/homedir that helps YOU connect to the DB but is not available in cron.

Answer (score 2):

that works. I was able to access the logs and I noticed that the problem was the environment variables.

so I simply insert "export ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = value" in my sh script which calls the perl script.

and there my perl script connects to the database normally.

Thanks.